# How to auto-start a network shortcut?

Tags: autostart

I have some applications on the network drive.  However, if I simply stick the shortcut in my "Startup" folder, it complains that the network drive is not available.

How do I add a networked shortcut to automatically run?

Comment: Have you tried setting it up to run with Task Scheduler?

Comment: Start your application from a script (cmd/vbs/ps) which tests the availability of a network drive (in cycle) and starts the app when the drive become available (or produces any warning message if it is not available during some time period). Put this script (or its shortcut/pathname) to any place of autostart entries.